# Selection of different value and conversion with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple selection with LINQ so structured:

```
var p = info.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLights
  .Where(x => x.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I")
  .GroupBy(x => x.PROGRESSIVO);

foreach (var item in p)
{
        // item. Do something
}
```

I must to select all the row in SPRicezioneSpedizioniLights with different PROGRESSIVO and elaborate each row.

When i try to elaborate item i have this error:

> 'System.Linq.IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the best way to do what i want?

Thank you

Comment: Show how you 'elaborate' your items.

Comment: Right now you are creating groups of items and iterating through the groups, not the items themselves.

Comment: nothing of particolar...i try to call an item of SPRicezioneSpedizioniLights, such as item.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE = "G";

Comment: What is the best mode to have all of the object that i need?

Comment: Why are you grouping?

Comment: I don't know how to have unique element for PROGRESSIVO. I want to salect all different row for PROGRESSIVO and elaborate each row. I am searching the best solution

Comment: @Ale So, you want to select rows with specific PROGRESSIVO and "elaborate" them?

Comment: Not with a specific PROGRESSIVO but all the rows with the first different PROGRESSIVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not with a specific PROGRESSIVO but all the rows with the first
>   different PROGRESSIVO

The problem is that result of GroupBy is `System.Linq.IGrouping` object that contains the key with a group of elements. 
So if you need first row from group you can use `FirstOrDefault()` method.

```
var p = info.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLights
          .Where(x => x.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE == "I")
          .GroupBy(x => x.PROGRESSIVO)
          .Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());

foreach(var item in p)
{
   if (item != null)
       item.SPEDIZIONE_STATO_GENERAZIONE = "G";
}
```

Comment: When i use this code I have an exception to "in":

Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `foreach` loop to get the detail of your groups.

```
 foreach (var groupingLevel in p)
 {
    // groupingLevel.Key

    foreach(var item in groupingLevel)
    {
       // item. Do something
    }               
 }
```